# Implicit inequality

Tags: geometry, inequality

I have a smooth function $F:\mathbb{R}_+^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}_+$. It holds that $F(0,0)=0$ and there exists a unique value $x^*>0$ such that $F(x^*,x^*)=x^*$. Furthermore, I know that the locus $\{(x,y)\,|\,y=F(y,x),x<x^*\}$ lies above the line $y=x$ and the locus $\{(x,y)\,|\,y=F(y,x),x>x^*\}$ lies below the line $y=x$. Finally, there exists a value $\bar x>0$ such that $F(\bar x,\bar x)>\bar x$. Can I conclude that $\bar x<x^*$ holds?

I tried to construct counterexamples but failed. Neither could I prove the claim. I would be willing to assume that $F$ is non-decreasing with respect to its second argument but even with this additional assumption I couldn't get anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with "lies below" and "lies above"? Is that a strict inequality? e.g. if 

$y = F(y,x)$ and $x < x^* \Rightarrow$ $x < y$

Comment: I mean strict inequalities. Formally: (i) $y=F(y,x)$ and $x<x^*$ implies $y>x$ and (ii) $y=F(y,x)$ and $x>x^*$ implies $y<x$.

Comment: If I understood your conditions right, wouldn’t $F(x,y)=xy$ give a counter e.g.  ?

Comment: @Macavity Your example does not satisfy my assumptions. If $F(y,x)=xy$, then it follows that $x^*=1$. The locus $\{(x,y)\,|\,y=F(y,x)\}$ is the union of the two lines $y=0$ and $x=x^*=1$. Hence, for $x<x^*$ this locus is below the diagonal, whereas I have assumed it to be above the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I don't think my initial idea works. However, I think
$F(y,x) = 2y^2 - x$ breaks the assumptions. Plot $2y^2 - x = y, 0 \leq x,y \leq 2$ to see, if everything is in order.

---

(Old idea here:)
I tried to give an explicit function, but it is quite hart. However assume you have a function $F$ that satisfies your assumptions in particular

$\bar{x} > x^* \Rightarrow F(\bar{x},\bar{x}) < \bar{x}$ (Contraposition)

Now we can take $\phi_{\bar{x}}$ a positive smooth function with compact support around $\bar{x}$ and define $\tilde{F} = F + C\phi_{\bar{x}}$ with $C>0$ big enough such that $\tilde{F}(\bar{x},\bar{x}) > \bar{x}$. If the support of the function $\phi_\bar{x}$ is chosen correctly it should not destroy the good properties of $F$.

So the answer is "no".

Comment: What do you mean by "compact support around $\bar x$"? I understand that $\phi_{\bar x}$ is a function mapping $\mathbb{R}_+^2$ to $\mathbb{R}_+$ (just like $F$). Wouldn't increasing $C$ affect the locus $\{(x,y)\,|\,y=F(y,x)\}$? How do you know that this locus is not shifted above the diagonal?

Comment: Yes you are right that will impact the "locus". My counterexample should show you however that your assumption unfortunately does not hold.